# Python3 help, 2 concurrently running tasks, one needs data from the other

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm not a Python programmer and i rarely work with linux but im forced to use it for a project.  The project is fairly straightforward, one task constantly gathers information as a single often updating numpy float32 value in a class, the other task that is also running constantly needs to occasionally grab the data in that variable asynchronously but not in very time critical way, and entirely on linux.  My default for such tasks is the creation of a thread but after doing some research it appears as if python threading might not be the best solution for this from what i'm reading.

So my question is this, do I use multithreading, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures, asyncio, or (just thinking out loud here) some stdin triggering / stdout reading trickery or something similar to DDS on linux that I don't know about, on 2 seperate running scripts?

Just to append, both tasks do a lot of IO, task 1 does a lot of USB IO, the other task does a bit serial and file IO. I'm not sure if this is useful.  I also think the importance of resetting the data once pulled and having as little downtime in task 1 as possible should be stated. Having 2 programs talk via a file probably won't satisfy this.

Any help would be appreciated, this has proven to be a difficult use case to google for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered a double ended queue? You write to one end and grab data from the other end. Then with your multi-threading you could write with one thread and read with the other:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque

Quoting the documentation: "Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction."

Answer (score 3):

Threading will probably work fine, a lot of the problems with the BKL (big kernel lock) are overhyped. You just need to make sure both threads provide active opportunities for the scheduler to switch contexts on a regular basis, typically by calling sleep(0). Most threads run in a loop and if the loop body is fairly short then calling sleep(0) at the top or bottom of it on every iteration is usually enough. If the loop body is long you might want to put a few more in along the way. It’s just a hint to the scheduler that this would be a good time to switch if other threads want to run.

Comment: Thank you, i gave threading a try and although fenicky and hard to debug, in the end it worked along with CowKeyMan's double ended queue suggestion